# BCP to bulk insert into a single row/field

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm trying to get BCP to insert the contents of a text file into a single field.

> **Example file content**
>
> Field1,field2,Field3
>
> 1,test,,
>
> 2,,test
>
> 3,test,test

The following command imports each line above as a new row into my temp table.

```
bcp mydb..tempTable in c:\testFile.txt -T -c
```

I think the solution is to use the -r switch to specify the row terminator as the end of the file but I'm unsure how to do this.

**EDIT**

I found the solution. The textfile I am importing is first created using the BCP, in my example all of the file contents comes from a single nvarchar(max) field and row. If I set the row terminator via -r during the export then this also becomes the end of my file. I can then import using `bcp mydb..tempTable in c:\testFile.txt -T -c -r {eof}`.

The only issue I have now is that the output from the BCP command states "Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file", however, the data still imports as I want so presumably I can ignore this?

Comment: You can sort-of safely ignore this error - if the final row doesn't specifically end with a row terminator, you'll get this message. But if you don't address it, you won't have any way of knowing if BCP is legitimately reporting an early EOF other than inspecting your data.